# Threading in BHO/ATL/COM. Winapi or something else?

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, atl, bho

I writing IE add-on and I'm using ATL for it. I need to create background worker thread so UI thread will be unblocked as soon as possible.
My question is, should I use the lowest possible way of creating thread which is Winapi, [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) etc.

Or is there other proffered way of creating worker thread in BHO/ATL/COM projects?

I have to learn this stuff first so I thought I would ask first ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use low-level APIs unless you need the level of control they offer.

With ATL you already have [`CWorkerThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w849dybf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but you could also use other libraries like [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's what I'm looking for. I don't want to add any excessive library for this simple task if I have something already. I tried to use this CWorkerThread but I still don't know how. Can you look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294629 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going all the way down to the API, then [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) is preferred over CreateThread() if your thread will use the CRT. (If you don't know, it probably will)

Comment: That problem was fixed a long time ago, CreateThread will work fine.  _getptd() in the crt source code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use boost::thread, the Visual Studio ConCRT, or Intel TBB, depending on how extreme your threading needs are. For the simplest uses, pick boost::thread. For the more advanced uses, pick the ConCRT or TBB. Don't use WinAPI unless you're seriously desperate for some feature not offered in the other libraries. The simple fact is that if you write a library in C++, then going to use the WinAPI for threads is like going back to assembler to write your program. Stay in C++ - use Boost.

Comment: Disagree with the API haterade.  I use the APIs all the time.  Lean, simple, easy.

Comment: @John: "simple" and "easy" are two words I've never before heard used to describe the Win32 API. Are we talking about the same thing here? I mean, it's occasionally underdocumented, *extemely* inconsistent and full of weird pitfalls and caveats and corner cases.

Comment: @John Dibling: There's nothing wrong with APIs- just the WinAPI. It's old, and intended for C. There's no reason to use it over the vastly superior boost::thread.

Comment: I think it is a bit nonsensical to bring in a high-level cross-platform library like boost for the sole purpose of managing a single background worker thread, particularly when your code base is necessarily platform-specific.